# Problems with running a Program with files

Tags: c, file

I have a school project and that project is making a C programming dictionary which will contain basic C statements and their meanings and uses. These statements and meanings will be inputted by me. Whatever I input will be stored in the file Dictionary.dat.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef struct
{
    char word[30], meaning[1000];
}lib;

void intro(void);
void updateword(FILE*,lib);
void addword(FILE*,lib);
void showMeaning(FILE*,lib);
void letter(FILE*,lib);
void showAll(FILE*,lib);


int main()
{
    char pass[8], choice;
    lib a;
    FILE *f=fopen("Dictionary.dat","a+b");


    printf("Enter Admin code: ");
    gets(pass);

    if(strcmp(pass,"turla")==0)
     {
          printf("Welcome to Admin page\n");

          printf("What will do?\n(U)-update\t(A)-Add Word\n(S)-Show All\t");
          printf("(L)-Show by Letter\n(M)-Show Meaning\n");
          while(choice!='E'||choice!='e')
           { 
             scanf("%c",&choice);

             if(f!=NULL)
              {
               switch(choice)
               {
                 case 'U':  updateword(f,a);break;
                 case 'A':  addword(f,a);break;
                 case 'S':  showAll(f,a);break;
                 case 'L':  letter(f,a);break;
                 case 'M':  showMeaning(f,a);break;
                 case 'E': printf("closing");break;
              }
             }

          }}
    else
      {
           printf("W e l c o m e   t o   C   P r o g r a m m i n g   D i c t i o n a r y !\n");
           printf("\t          A Dictionary for C programming terms\n\n");
           printf("What would you want to do? do?\n\n (S)-Search terms\t(L)-Search by letter\n(A)-Show All\n");


           scanf("%c",&choice);
           while(choice!='E'||choice!='e')
           {
            intro();
            switch(choice)
              {
                 case 'A':
                 case 'a':  showAll(f,a); break;
                 case 'L':  
                 case 'l': letter(f,a); break;
                 case 'S':
                 case 's':  showMeaning(f,a); break;
                 case 'E':
                 case 'e': printf("closing..."); break;
              }
              }
            system("cls");
      }
      fclose(f);
      getch();
      return 0;
}

void intro(void)
{
     printf("W e l c o m e   t o   C   P r o g r a m m i n g   D i c t i o n a r y !\n");
           printf("\t          A Dictionary for C programming terms\n\n");
           printf("What would you want to do? do?\n\n (S)-Search terms\t(L)-Search by letter\n(A)-Show All\n");
}

void updateword(FILE*ptr,lib a)
{
     char srchWrd[30],choice,qtn='Y';

     printf("Enter Word to update: ");
     gets(srchWrd);

     while(fread(&a,sizeof(lib),1,ptr))
     {
     system("cls");
      if(strcmp(srchWrd,a.word)==0)
       {
        printf("What will you change? (W)-Word (M)-Meaning");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        while(qtn!='N'||qtn!='n')
        {
          switch(choice)
          {
            case 'W':
            case 'w': gets(a.word); printf("Do you still want to edit?(Y/N): "); scanf("%c",&qtn); break;
            case 'M':
            case 'm': gets(a.meaning); printf("Do you still want to edit?(Y/N): "); scanf("%c",&qtn); break;
            default: printf("Invalid option. Enter Again");
          }
        }
        fseek(ptr,sizeof(lib)*-1,1);
        fwrite(&a,sizeof(lib),1,ptr);
       }}
}  


void addword(FILE*ptr,lib a)
{


       printf("Enter word: ");fflush(stdin);
       gets(a.word);
       printf("Enter Meaning: ");fflush(stdin);
       gets(a.meaning);

       fwrite(&a,sizeof(lib),1,ptr);

}



void showMeaning(FILE*ptr,lib a)
{
     char wrd[30];
     int ctr=0;

     printf("Search: ");
     gets(wrd);

     while(fread(&a,sizeof(lib),1,ptr))
     {
       if(strcmp(wrd,a.word)==0)
       {
         printf("\t%s",a.meaning);
         ctr ++;
       }
     }

     if(ctr==0)
       printf("No word or symbol found in Dictionary");

}


void letter(FILE*ptr,lib a)
{
     char ltr;
     int ctr;

     printf("Enter Letter");
     scanf("%c",&ltr);

     while(fread(&a,sizeof(lib),1,ptr))
     {
       if(ltr==a.word[0])
       {
           printf("%s - %s",a.word,a.meaning);
           ctr++;
       }
     }

     if(ctr==0)
       printf("No search results");
}


void showAll(FILE*ptr,lib a)
{
    while(fread(&a,sizeof(lib),1,ptr))
         printf("%s - %s",a.word,a.meaning);
}
```

I have problems inputting the first word because It will always ask me to enter a word even if the else statement terminates. I am using C language, not C++.

Comment: It's nice to show some context but could you point out the lines that are causing the problem?

Comment: You are reading input directly from `stdin` and you do so with mixed calls to `scanf("%c")` and `gets`. These calls don't mix too well. Also, especially `scanf("%c")` doesn't do what you expect; it doesn't read a keypress, but it reads the next char from a buffered stream. It would be better if you used line-based input with `fgets` (not `gets`!) throughout and read even single-character input from a line.

Comment: @TomFenech I really have no Idea where the problem is. All i know is that it compiles perfectly. The problem is when running it.

Comment: @MOehm so you mean if I do a gets or scanf, I should use fgets and fscanf?

Comment: in `open` call, there is no parameter `"a+b"`. it just `"a+"` or `"w+"` or `"r+"`. And remove `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: I have a pdf file from a teacher and it pretty much says that a+b is a mode. Link of the pdf she made https://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/attachment.php?attach_id=572e540e7faa1788a5e4811a0b55c4f5&mid=mid.1400401750290%3Ae4332d9e9ce85b7845&hash=AQBR4Yi0vcWsMZYb

Comment: @SGG the "b" part means that the file is opened in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. You problem is at this line.

```
while(choice!='E'||choice!='e')
```

You're using `OR` operation instead of `AND` operation. So, that line should be

```
while((choice != 'E') && (choise != 'e')).
```

---

**Why your code failed when entering `e` or `E`:**

If you entered `e` then,

```
while( `e` != `E` || `e` != `e`)
        ----------
           ^
        returns true. so controller goes to the while loop.
```

same with `E` too.

**How `&&` works:**

If you entered `e` then,

```
while( `e` != `E` && `e` != `e`)
        ----------
           ^
        returns true and checks second condition


while( `e` != `E` || `e` != `e`)
        ----------    --------- 
           ^             ^
        returns true.    returns false. Condition failed. Don't enter into while.
```

---

Edit: 2nd problem

In `else` block, in `switch-case` add this instruction:

```
scanf("%c",&choice);
```

ohterwise your loop executes continuously.

Comment: the program still doesnt write anything

Comment: @Jefferson What are the inputs you are giving?

Comment: I know what it means and I did what you told me. The problem is, I still cant write anything. Can you try to compile and run it? Enter the admin code and add a new word. There, you will see the problem.

Comment: first, what is `"a+b"` in `open` instruction

Comment: any input for the word and for the meaning as long as it writes it in the file. I am the one responsible of what to write but I could not write anything in the file

Comment: @Jefferson. have you tried with just "a+"?? there is no "a+b" kinda thing.

Comment: My teacher said I need to use a .bat file so txt is not allowed :(

Comment: then I don't know about `.bat` file. Because I'm only familiar with gcc and linux not windows

Comment: .bat file is a binary type file. Anyways, can you try running my program?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be verious issues with your program. I'll address the mixed `scanf` and `gets` input I've hinted at in my comment here.

When you want to add an entry, you type 'A'. Nothing happens. That's because the input is buffered and is not sent to the program until a new-line was received, i.e. until the user presses return. Which the user does, of course, because nothing happend when 'A' was pressed. The 'A' still sits in the buffer, however. Now you ask the user to provide a word, which is read from the bufer with `gets`, which reads input until the end of a line is found.

But yout input bufer looks like this:

```
A    newline    w   o   r   d   newline
```

The 'A' has been consumed by `scanf`, but the newline hasn't. The next line you read is an empty line.

I suggest that you write a little framework for your most typical cases: Picking an item from a menu by typing a single letter plus newline and readlin a line of input. This still won't be ideal, because the normal input from the terminal doesn't lend itself to fancy menus, but it's a start. You should look into `ncurses` or possibly the options in `<conio.h>` if you want to write pretty DOS-style menus.

Anyway, here's a suggestion that should get you an idea:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



int read_key()
{
    char buf[40];
    char key;

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) return -1;
    if (sscanf(buf, " %c", &key) == 0) return 0;
    return key;
}

int read_line(char *buf, int max)
{
    int len;

    if (fgets(buf, max, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
    len = strlen(buf);
    if (len) buf[--len] = '\0';
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char buf[40];
    int key;
    int len;

    printf("\nW e l c o m e !\n\n");

    for(;;) {
        printf("    (L) Look\n");
        printf("    (R) Register\n");
        printf("    (Q) Quit\n");
        printf("\n");
        key = read_key();

        switch (key) {
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            printf("You are in the school library in a maze of "
                "twisted aisles, all different.");
            break;

        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            printf("Enter your name:\n");
            len = read_line(buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (len < 0) goto quit;
            if (len) {
                printf("Your name is %d letters (and spaces) long.\n", len);
            }
            break;

        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
        case -1:
        quit:
            printf("Goodbye.\n");
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Oh, the letter '%c'. That's not on the menu.\n", key);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I haven't looked too closely at the rest of your code, but it doesn't look too solid to me. For example, the `showAll` function is horrid with a never-ending `while` loop and an ad-hoc `fread` where you should probably be using `fgets`. It is also customary to keey a dictionary in memory and commit the changes to disk after the program has terminated.